# problems with url in foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am showing the URLs of my menu in a foreach, however in the view it is not shown correctly. How could I make them show up correctly?

Inside the foreach I am showing them in the following way:

```
$horarios .= "<li class='active'><a href='<?= base_url('index.php/C_Horarios'); ?>'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i>Administrar Horarios</a></li>";
```

This in the view is shown as follows

[image]

When should I show in this way

[image]

Comment: Close the string encapsulation so it processes as PHP. e.g. instead of `<a href='<?=` have `<a href='<?=" . base_url`

Comment: This does not work, it stays the same

Comment: Update the question with your attempt.

Comment: @chris85 is on the right track! But the php begin and end tags were still in the assignment.

Comment: `I tried it this way but it still looks like in the picture` ... how is that even possible? That is logically impossible on multiple levels :) unless you have a code leak from somewhere else.... Please look over all your lines of code, and look for more of those `<?= ?>` in variable assignments.

Comment: I just realized that I was testing this line in a view that can not be accessed without an administrator account, probe with an administrator account and it worked hahaha I'm a bit confused today XD Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing php inline inside of php assignment. You have:

```
$horarios .= "<li class='active'><a href='<?= base_url('index.php/C_Horarios'); ?>'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i>Administrar Horarios</a></li>";
```

When it really should be:

```
$horarios .= "<li class='active'><a href='". base_url('index.php/C_Horarios') ."'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i>Administrar Horarios</a></li>";
```

Please note the differences. Its subtle, but it makes a world of difference in expected behavior when assigning a string to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for answering, although this does not work, it remains the same as before

Comment: Really? Then PLEASE add your full code, because I cannot see how on earth that would be true.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000943/undefined-property-in-foreach/47000999?noredirect=1#comment80950843_47000999

Comment: Add the link, because I had asked a previous question that I had in the foreach, but it was solved previously. This contains the complete code

Comment: I'm sorry. But you are trying to begin an inline php block, inside of an already started variable assignment. The only way you can clear that `<?= ?>` stuff from the href="" url is to follow what I put above in the example. Thats all there is to it really.

Comment: Edit the question